# Can I add parameters to my middleware via my RouteServiceProvider?

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Can pass along parameters to my middleware via my RouteService Provider where I map the route groups?

In my RouteServiceProvider.php

```
protected function mapAdminRoutes()
{
    Route::prefix('api/admin')
         ->middleware('admin:admin')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
}
```

In my Kernal.php

```
    'admin' => [
        'api',
        'permission' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyPermission::class,
    ],
```

Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\Permission;
use Closure;

class VerifyPermission
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $permission)
    {
        dd($permission);
    }
}
```

I figured if you can add a parameter to your middleware this way

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'permission:admin'], function () {}
```

You must be able to do it in your RouteServiceProvider aswell right? I don't want to use route groups in my route files, so api.php or admin.php

So to summarize I want to inject parameters into my middleware by just using my Kernal.php and my RouteServiceProvider.php. I made all these nice route files to group all my routes without using actual groups in those files that make for messy code. And now I still need to inject parameters like this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['permission:admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/test', 'TestController@test');
});
```

I know you can use the constructor of a controller to do it but this is also not what I want. It should be solvable by just using the Kernal.php and RouteServiceProvider right? Because the groups are defined there so you should be able to pass what group you are using.

Comment: I think you should be adding the middleware to your route. so for example:
Route::middleware('super')->post('promote/{permissionID}/user/{userID}', 'UserController@promote');

Comment: I don't want to add middleware to my route that way. They are already in a middleware group that takes care of that.